# SPSS: Compute new variable - people who match 3+ of 12 variables?

Tags: spss

I hope to explain this accurately.

I have 12 dichotomous variables (yes/no) for which I want to compute a new variable that includes those who answered Yes to 3 or more of these 12 variables.

I'm a bit soft on my programming these days so am having difficulty constructing a statement (in the GUI - not as syntax).

Can anyone offer some help/guidance how I may accomplish this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Compute threeplus = sum(x1 to x12) >= 3.